# How would one refer to/address a Shogun?

Tags: japan, language

In the [Bakumatsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakumatsu) era, how would one refer to a [shogun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogun) (when talking about him with someone else) or address him directly if talking to him? Is it just name + -sama suffix?

I am interest in the answer from both a shogun loyalist perspective (e.g a member of the [Shinsengumi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinsengumi)) and from an anti-shogunal/pro-imperialist perspective.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would fit better to http://japanese.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, I was asking here because I asked a native Japanese speaker and she didn't know because she wasn't familiar with the historical details.

Comment: That's a point. However, I still think you'd be more likely to have luck there.

Comment: @user232670 sadly it is a very grammatical question, and I doubt many people can speak Japanese here. I don't think your question is bad, but relates less to history, you will have way better chance to get a good answer on the japanese stackexchange than here. Good luck there!

Comment: Can we not leave this open, as it is historical, and interesting? or must we close EVERYthing? Just because one doesn't know the answer doesn't mean someone else might, and there are actually one or two knowledgable people about the Japanese history here....

Comment: Indeed, this close-mania of this site only reminds us that the community is its own greatest enemy. @CGCampbell

Comment: I don't think normal people got to talk to the Shogun. His immediate retainers would address the Shogun as oyakata-sama, and a very close and respected subordinate in private conversation might address him as tono.

Comment: Interesting, so that's the same way you address a Sumo coach? So then does this imply the shogun never really went out in public (locked away in a room) and only ever interacted with the daimyo?

Comment: @user232670 Are you addressing my comment and trying to be snide? Shoguns don't go walking around in the street hobnobbing with commoners. When they travelled, they used a palanquin.

Comment: @TylerDurden No not being snide (and sorry if it came out that way). I am quite genuinely interested in how the shogun interacted back then. It seems like it's quite easy to get information on his achievements and what he did at a high level but details like these seem a tad harder to find.

Comment: Closing a question like this was ridonkulous. We should keep doing stupid things like that if we want this community to remain tiny.

Comment: Note that Japanese honorifics are about relative rank, not absolute rank.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_honorifics#Sama.  Don't confuse them with the Western practice of giving titles.  I also don't see how this has anything to do with history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two forms of address that might be used: oyakata-sama and tono. Tono is somewhat less formal.

If speaking about him in the third person, a person might say *watakushitachi no tono* ("our lord"), or even his name with -sama. In some cases, well-known figures had popular nicknames.

Comment: Thank you, that answers most of what I was after. What about when the anti-shogunal imperialist were to talk about him (during the end of the bakumatsu period when he was unpopular)? would they have still used the same forms of address out of habit (or fear) or would they have dropped any formality and just openly call him by name?

Comment: I doubt that the Shogun would have been admitting any commoners into his presence. Even after they took over the imperial palace and held some kangaroo court to strip him of his lands, he just sent a protest message. He did not appear in person.

Answer (score 0):

Oyakata-sama is what his/her troops would most likely call the Lord, it is something people below the Lord would refer to him/her as.

When it's came to the Shogun himself it would vary but I'm sure -sama would be included with their last name such as Tokugawa-sama, Ieyasu-sama, etc. It is a sign of superiority, then again they can go with the full title of Sei-i Taishogun, even being given the chance to see the Shogun through multitudes of guards and schedules you'd be expected to do something.

Comment: Sources / links would improve your answer and get you more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Tono sama was the most used term by the shoguns close subordinates. E.G. in the long-rin Abarenbo Shogun drama.

Comment: Do you have an academic source?